# Use Joomla template in non joomla site

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I need to create a php page to load Joomla template and assign data to its component. I do it for learning purposes and may be it will be useful in future. I tried to read on internet but there are almost no (as per my findings) tutorial that explains that. I would e happy to get direction and even joomla file(s) that do loading so that I can learn from there.
Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, what do you intend to learn from this ?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. If you need to run a Joomla template outside a Joomla environment, I'd recommend to adapt the template to suit your needs in your particular application.

Comment: @Bob learning how joomla does load templates

Comment: @jjmontes I know it is bad Idea but I wanted to learn anyway. Sometimes I love to learn weird things ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a basic tutorial that gave me a light on how things work [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/creating-your-first-joomla-template/)